# BigDump Error with MyISAM table

Tags: php, mysql, database, import, myisam

I'm trying to import a a database using BigDump but it is giving me this error:

```
Error at the line 238: ) ENGINE=MyISAM */;
Query: `username` varchar(64),
`name` varchar(255),
`entityRef` int(11),
`Date` date,
`contactName` varchar(255),
`email` varchar(255),
`tel` varchar(128),
`Qualifies` varchar(3)
) ENGINE=MyISAM */
MySQL: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'`username` varchar(64), `name` varchar(255), `entityRef` int(11), `Date` d' at line 1
```

I am totally stumped with this one as I have used BigDump before with no problems.

How can I fix this?

---

Here is the block in the sql file being imported:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `_funnel`;
/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `_funnel`*/;
SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;
/*!50001 CREATE TABLE `_funnel` (
`username` varchar(64),
`name` varchar(255),
`entityRef` int(11),
`Date` date,
`contactName` varchar(255),
`email` varchar(255),
`tel` varchar(128),
`Qualifies` varchar(3)
) ENGINE=MyISAM */;
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
```

Also I have a few views in my exported SQL file. Could this be an issue?

Comment: have you tried to remove */ after MyISAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is updated sql, I put the comments after ;.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `_funnel`;
/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `_funnel`;*/
SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;
/*!50001 CREATE TABLE `_funnel` (
`username` varchar(64),
`name` varchar(255),
`entityRef` int(11),
`Date` date,
`contactName` varchar(255),
`email` varchar(255),
`tel` varchar(128),
`Qualifies` varchar(3)
) ENGINE=MyISAM ;*/
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
```

But you should create the table I think. Why you are putting comments in creation statement

Comment: Thanks, phpmyadmin must have issues with exporting views? Fortunate that is all I lost, blood pressure returning to normal :D

Comment: Accept answer if issue has been fixed :)